# Use view to inflate multiple times

Tags: android, inflate

I have a some problem regarding inflating and re-using the same TextView. 
Its like its trying to overwrite the same textview over and over again or something and it cant do that?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mainlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.days_monday_inflate, null);
View layout_number = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_number, null);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    row = new TableRow(this);
    number = (TextView) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.Number);
    number.setTag(i);
    number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    row.addView(number);
}
setContentView(mainlayout);
```

Here is the inflate_number.xml

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="1" />
```

This is the error im getting and its on row: 51, which is:
    `row.addView(number);`

```
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at com.trainingschedule.days.Monday.onCreate(Monday.java:50)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 20:54:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(1166):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're never actually adding any Views to your Activity. You're creating new TableRows and adding TextViews to them, but you're never adding the rows to anything. Assuming you have a TableLayout in `R.layout.days_monday_inflate`, you should first get a reference to that view (`TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_table_layout_id)`) and then add each row to that TableLayout:

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_table_layout_id);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    row = new TableRow(this);
    View layout_number = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_number, layout, false);
    TextView number = (TextView) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.Number);
    number.setTag(i);
    number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    row.addView(number);
    layout.addView(row);
}
```

Although I would recommend setting up your layout fully in XML if at all possible, unless needed dynamically. Also, if you're only adding one TextView per row, you're better off just using a LinearLayout, I would suggest.

Comment: Thanks alot! Have been sitting with this for about 2 hours now, abit noobish. But now I can continue developing on my application, awesome!!

Comment: One thing to note is you have to pass that null when you inflate, because if you try to attach it to a view group there inflate () will return the view group and your findViewById will still return the first instance of the id not the new one.

Comment: @mikethematrix Actually, I now realize passing null is the wrong approach. You should in fact pass the parent layout in, but also pass in `false` as the last parameter to prevent attaching it to the layout immediately (allowing you to get a reference to it). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setTag(i) didn't work, what worked was changing the id after inflating the layout but before adding it to the parent view like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mainlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.days_monday_inflate, null);
View layout_number = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_number, null);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    row = new TableRow(this);
    number = (TextView) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.Number);
    number.setId(i); //THIS IS THE KEY STEP
    number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    row.addView(number);
}
setContentView(mainlayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a single TextView to multiple rows, which is what is causing your error. You'll need to reinflate layout_number each time to get a new TextView.

I'm not sure what is contained within your layout_number file, but based off what you have here, it seems like you might be better served to create new TextViews inside your loop ala

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    row = new TableRow(this);
    number = new TextView(this);
    number.setTag(i);
    number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    row.addView(number);
}
```

Comment: I get the same error if im using `number = new TextView(this);` And the error is on row 50 now which is `number.setText(Integer.toString(i));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View mainlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.days_monday_inflate, null);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    row = new TableRow(this);
    View layout_number = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_number, null);
    TextView number = (TextView) layout_number.findViewById(R.id.Number);
    number.setTag(i);
    number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    row.addView(number);
}
```

Comment: Now I dont get any errors but, nothing is showing on the screen, is it because Im not targeting the TableLayout in my `R.layout.days_monday_inflate`?

Comment: I was wondering about this, I thought you left out some code. You need to add your TableRow instances to a TableLayout. e.g. TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this); ... tableLayout.addView(row); <- add the table row.

Comment: Do I need to do this on each for-loop circle or after my for-loop? Because I have a TableLayout in my days_monday_inflate I want to use

Comment: If you have a TAbleLayout in R.layout.days_monday, then you can extract it from its inflated view. e.g. TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutId); and you just need to do this outside of the loop. But the adding the TableRow to the tablelayout must be inside the loop.