# Android Inflate layout to use inside TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to build a table in android dynamically. But when I attempt to inflate a view, for instance, table_cell.xml, and add it to my table row, nothing appears:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

View tableCell = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, container, false);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());

tableRow.addView(tableCell);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

On the other hand, if I just create a TextView manually, then add it to the row, it seems to work fine. Can anyone help me figure out why adding an inflated layout doesn't work?

Comment: I think you should try with getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, tableRow, true); and you should not add the tableCell view on the tableRow manually in this case..

Comment: @Cata - This worked, if you would like to write out an answer I will give you credit.

Comment: Done, added below with a small extra explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with 
`getActivity().getLayoutInflater() .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, tableRow, true);`

And you should not add the `tableCell` view on the `tableRow` manually in this case as the inflator method takes care of that since we pass true ..

Comment: This works, thanks! In my case, I had to re-use an inflated layout multiple times.  So what I did was set the last param to `false` .. and then was able to add the view on my own after giving it a unique id .. like so `inflatedLayout.setId(i); tableRow.addView(inflatedLayout);` .. thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26619620/2162226

Answer (score 0):

Try This
You have to provide id for positioning.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

View tableCell = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, container, false);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());

tableRow.addView(tableCell);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow,id);
```

or

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

View tableCell = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, container, false);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());

TableRow.LayoutParams LP = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

tableRow.setLayoutParams(LP);
tablerow.setId(ID);


tableRow.addView(tableCell);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

or

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

View tableCell = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.table_cell, container, false);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());


tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
tablerow.setId(ID);


tableRow.addView(tableCell);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```