# Scrollview - How do you make a scroll view display 2 children at a time yet still relative to the screen size?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, children

I'm wondering if there is any way to make the children inside a ScrollView only show 2 children at a time. I have tried making the layout heights of each children = 0dp and setting the weight but it displays all the children at once. 
I have tried setting the children heights to a specific amount and it works but only for my certain screen size.

Here is my sample code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_weight=".5"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#7458ff"
        android:layout_weight=".5"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#56ffe3"
        android:layout_weight=".5"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight=".5"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#fffd69"
        android:layout_weight=".5"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here is what it looks like when I set the view height to 0dp and use weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHG9f.png)

[But I only want it to display 2 at a time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubV7Q.png)

Comment: do you want to make this for first and second linear layout ? OR everytime you go to this layout you need only two layout at that screen after scrolling ?@Potato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One sollution is to set height of each child programmaticaly like

```
view.getLayoutParams().height = getHalfScreenSize();
```

And the half screen size like this:

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics).heightPixels/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LayoutInflater ? You have an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code/5488652#5488652) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661688/android-inflate-layout-to-use-inside-tablerow)

Comment: Do you mean adding all of the children into one horizontal layout? I'm trying to figure out how to display these horizontal layouts inside a vertical layout. x.x

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your code sample, you try to add elements in your horizontal linear layout. Use LayoutInflater to add scrollview elements dynamically.

Comment: You'll have to design a template layout, and inflate it as an element of your scroll view.